# Vue: Proper use of async/await within a function?

Tags: vue.js

I'm still trying to get used to async/await but I think I'm missing something. I have a button that with a `@click` that calls `submitFinalAssets`. Inside `submitFinalAssets()`, I am trying to see if there are images waited to be uploaded. If so, then I want to call `triggerDropzoneUpload()` and wait for that to finish before executing the rest of the code in `submitFinalAssets()`.

```
methods: {

 triggerDropzoneUpload: function() {
        if (this.$refs.myVueDropzone.getActiveFiles()) {
            return this.$refs.myVueDropzone.processQueue();
        } else {
        return;
    },

    submitFinalAssets: async function() {
        if (!this.note) {
            this.showError = true;
        }
    
        await this.triggerDropzoneUpload();
        
        axios.post('/upload-urls', {
           image:  this.imageUrl,
        })
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. It's not clear from your post what your actual question is. Could you please [edit your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63044108/edit) and describe your problem more clearly? What is it you expect to happen and what is actually happening? Are you getting any errors? That sort of thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also have to `await` the axios post request as it is asynchronous.

```js
submitFinalAssets: async function() {
    if (!this.note) {
        this.showError = true;
    }

    await this.triggerDropzoneUpload();

    await axios.post('/upload-urls', { // put the await keyword here to wait for the asynchronous axios post request
       image:  this.imageUrl,
    })
});
```

For more information on async await, this [post](https://javascript.info/async-await) does a good job of explaining it.

Comment: thanks Tony.  How does it know when `triggerDropzoneUpload()` is done.  The function inside of there, `this.$refs.myVueDropzone.processQueue()`, is a function in the Dropzone library.

Comment: what about `await this.triggerDropzoneUpload()`?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone yep, that's what I'm doing, `await this.triggerDropzoneUpload()`, but inside of that calls `this.$refs.myVueDropzone.processQueue()` .  I'm just curious  what signals that `await this.triggerDropzoneUpload()` is completed?  Will it definitely wait for `this.$refs.myVueDropzone.processQueue()` to be completed ?

Comment: Hi, @timmyLtus, you use `async-await` if the function returns a promise. If you are absolutely sure that the `this.triggerDropzoneUpload` method returns a promise (is asynchronous), you can store the value of the request in a variable.

Something like `const isUploadDone = await this.triggerDropzoneUpload()`
if (isUploadDone) {
 // put what you want it done here
}

Usually, you can check that the variable holds a value before continuing. I hope this helps.

Comment: I really don't see how this answers the question. Unless OP was trying to do something else **after** `submitFinalAssets` completed, this makes no difference as to when it executes _"the rest of the code in `submitFinalAssets()`"_

Comment: @Phil, `"I'm still trying to get used to async/await but I think I'm missing something"` From that statement, it was clear that his code wasn't working even after awaiting the `this.triggerDropzoneUpload();` method. I saw that he didn't wait for the axios post request to complete which would certainly make the code not to behave as expected. In the comments section, he asked a further question which I proceeded to answer. I don't know why my answer has been downvoted. Stackoverflow really has to regulate the downvote feature.